# Getting warning with a pointer to a pointer and NSError

Tags: objective-c

I do not understand the following warning:

Incompatible pointer types sending 'NSError *__strong *' to parameter of type 'NSString *__autoreleasing *'

The method that throw this is

```
BSSPhoneNumberFormatter *formatter = [[BSSPhoneNumberFormatter alloc] init];
NSString *tmp = self.dtlPhnNbr.text;
id objectValue;
NSError *error;
[formatter getObjectValue:&objectValue forString:tmp errorDescription:&error];
```

The last line has the warning.

The h file for the BSSPhoneNumberFormatter is

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface BSSPhoneNumberFormatter : NSFormatter

@end
```

And the method is

```
- (BOOL)getObjectValue:(id *)anObject forString:(NSString *)string errorDescription:(NSString **)error {
    *anObject = (id)[self stripNonDigits:string];
    return YES;
}
```

I understand that (NSString **) error is a pointer to a pointer. A different post said to replace (NSString **) with (NSString *) both in the method that is called and in the calling method, but if I do that I get hard errors.

What is going on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your last parameter in method:

```
- (BOOL)getObjectValue:(id *)anObject forString:(NSString *)string errorDescription:(NSString **)error
```

is

```
errorDescription:(NSString **)error
```

which is pointer to a pointer to NSString but you are passing NSError instead.
Change the call to:

```
NSString *error; <-- Change object type to NSString here
[formatter getObjectValue:&objectValue forString:tmp errorDescription:&error];
```

You can also replace method to accept NSError** as a argument instead of NSString**. It depends what suit your project requirements best.

Comment: I understand now. Kind of a stupid error. Thank you, works perfectly now.